# tortoisesvn can NOT access Encrypting File System repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, ntfs, encrypting-file-system

My system is Win7
If My repository folder is encrypted, then I can NOT get the log or browser it.
why?

If i use file:///F:/SVNsystem/AVRsensor/trunk, I can access the repository
but http://canson/svn/AVRsensor/trunk, there is something wrong!

I have find the answer.
the apache is log on as system, then the system has no right to access the EFS file.
So I add a user apache, and load the current user's 'persional information exchange-PKCS"
then in serivces, set the apache log on as user apache. restart the APACHE service.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience (using VisualSVN), the reason you can not access the repository when EFS is enabled, is the SVN service is running under a different user name (Network Service). One solution is to run the SVN service using your user name. Doing this requires allowing your user account to sign in as a service which likely has other security implications.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably related to your web server. You are probably using Apache for its svn support and Apache server cannot access your encrypted files. Use windows authentication in your web server.